# Returning ListView from funciton makes Flutter Column blank

Tags: flutter, dart

Whenever I put this on my Column of widgets, the entire column gets blank. If I take this off, it works:

```
Widget productsList(List<Product> products) {
  List<ListTile> p = products.map((product) => _product(product)).toList();
  return new ListView(children: p);
}

ListTile _product(Product product) => ListTile(
      title: Text(product.name,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            fontSize: 20,
          )),
      subtitle: Text(product.quantity.toString()),
      leading: Icon(
        Icons.shopping_basket,
        color: Colors.blue[500],
      ),
    );
```

Here's how I'm using it:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Pedido " + _order.orderNumber.toString()),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            orderItem("Nome: ", _order.clientName),
            productsList(_order.products)
          ],
        ));
  }
```

I can't see anything wrong. I'm returning a `ListView` as a `Widget`

Comment: Try wrapping the `productsList(_order.products)` in an `Expanded` widget. Let me know whether it's working or not?

Comment: @VinothVino it works but it expands too much. Is it the rigth solution? I now understand that a ListView must have a size. I tried putting Expandable>Container with fixed height>my ListView but it still expands all it can

Comment: Also, add mainAxisSize to a minimum size in the column. Then wrap the product list in an Expanded widget.

Comment: Add shrinkWrap to true in the listview, so that they occupy spaces only it needs.

Comment: Is my answer solved your problem? @Guelando OCs

Comment: @VinothVino yes thanks and sorry for the delay, I was gonna accept anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `shrinkWrap` to `true` in the `productsList` widget.

`ListView(children: p, shrinkWrap: true);`

Then wrap the `productsList` inside the `Expanded` widget and also add the property `mainAxisSize` to a `minimum` size in the `Column` widget.